# boost::transform vs std::transform

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, transform, std

From the snippet below should I conclude that `std::transform` is to be preferred over `boost::transform` as probably more efficient because the former uses fewer initialisations and destructors than the latter?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
class Ftor {
public:
    Ftor(const Ftor& rhs) : t(rhs.t)
    { std::cout << " Ftor : copy\n"; }
    Ftor(float rate) : t(rate)
    { std::cout << " Ftor : init\n"; }
    ~Ftor()
    { std::cout << "~Ftor : ...\n"; }
    float operator() (float x) { return x < t ? 0.0 : 1.0; }
private:
    float t;
};

typedef std::vector<float> vec_t;

int main (void) 
{
    vec_t arg(/*...*/);
    vec_t val(arg.size());
    float x = 1.0;
    /* Standard transform test */
    std::cout << "Standard transform:\n";
    std::transform(arg.begin(), arg.end(), val.begin(), Ftor(x));
    std::cout << "Boost transform:\n";
    /* Boost transform test */
    boost::transform(boost::make_iterator_range(arg.begin(), arg.end()),
                     val.begin(), Ftor(x));
}
```

Output:

```
Standard transform:
 Ftor : init
~Ftor : ...
Boost transform:
 Ftor : init
 Ftor : copy
~Ftor : ...
~Ftor : ...
```

Standard transform uses 2 calls. Boost transform uses 4 calls. Standard transform wins. Or does it...?

**ADDENDUM**

As @sehe suggested `std::ref` saves one constructor per call to `transform` with which `boost::transform` uses only one call. But `std::ref` cannot take a temporary as argument. But then, passing `Ftor f(x)` is fine since the latter has a definite address.

Accounting for the constructor/destructor calls when transform is called inside a loop. I've two options with boost now:

```
std::cout << "with std::ref\n";
for (/*...*/) {
    x = ...;
    f = Ftor(x);
    boost::transform(arg, val.begin(), std::ref(f));
}

std::cout << "with temporary\n";
for (/*...*/) {
    x = ...;
    boost::transform(arg, val.begin(), Ftor(x));
}
```

Output:

```
with std::ref
 Ftor : init
 Ftor : init
 ...
~Ftor : ...
with temporary
 Ftor : init
 Ftor : copy
~Ftor : ...
~Ftor : ...
 Ftor : init
 Ftor : copy
~Ftor : ...
~Ftor : ...
 ...
```

I've got a gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
with or without `-O3` yields the same results.

Whether the constructor/destructor is "expensive" is relative to the `operator()`. It a final product, it is going to perform not too demanding math, not dissimilar to the example above.

[Complete example on coliru](//coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdf5402070ec1d37)

Comment: The edit makes little to no sense. Why is the member variable `t` not even used in the functor?

Comment: `return (x<t?1.:0.);`

Comment: Oh god. I really need my eyes checked. Regardless, awaiting benchmark code (or perhaps what the code is trying to achieve. There could be better algorithmic approaches)

Comment: re. Edit. That [Complete example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdf5402070ec1d37) just counts the things that you shouldn't be counting, again. Where's the actual _benchmark_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

STL algorithms are allowed to copy their predicate/functors. This mostly happens because they're passed by value.

What you see is that `boost` does *one* more forward call.

### Is there a problem?

Not usually. Compilers are very good at inlining, copy elision and dependency analysis.

Chances are, the code generated ends up being exactly the same.

> *Of course, adding the `cout` statements completely wrecks that. Compare generated code **without** the constructor/destructor side-effects spoiling it!*

Fair comparison [using no-side-effects](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52a7a1f5d0ce708b) generates **identical** code for the STL and Boost variants: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14544891/

### Fix

The way STL (and boost algorithms) was designed, you can pass the functor by reference explicitly, if you want. You use `std::ref` for this:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06a6e5387417267e)</kbd>**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

class Ftor {
  public:
    Ftor(const Ftor &rhs) : t(rhs.t) { std::cout << " Ftor : copy" << std::endl; } 
    Ftor(float rate) : t(rate)       { std::cout << " Ftor : init" << std::endl; } 
    ~Ftor()                          { std::cout << "~Ftor : ..."  << std::endl; } 
    float operator()(float x)        { return x; }  

  private:
    float t;
};

typedef std::vector<float> vec_t;

int main(void) {
    vec_t arg(190, 1), val(arg.size());

    {
        std::cout << "STL transform: " << std::endl;
        Ftor f(1.0);
        std::transform(arg.begin(), arg.end(), val.begin(), std::ref(f));
    }
    std::cout << "-----\n";

    {
        std::cout << "Boost transform: " << std::endl;
        Ftor f(1.0);
        boost::transform(arg, val.begin(), std::ref(f));
    }
    std::cout << "-----\n";
}
```

Prints

```
STL transform: 
Ftor : init
~Ftor : ...
-----
Boost transform: 
Ftor : init
~Ftor : ...
-----
```

---

**NOTE** Regardless of everything it's *very very ironic* to use a range algorithm on a container and construct a range `boost::make_iterator_range(arg.begin(), arg.end())` instead of just using `arg`:

```
boost::transform(arg, val.begin(), Ftor(x));
```

Comment: Fair comparison [using no-side-effects](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52a7a1f5d0ce708b) generates **identical** code for the STL and Boost variants: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14544891/

Comment: upvoted for the fair comparison... and the ironic remark :D

Comment: If I replace the line near the end `boost::transform(arg, val.begin(), std::ref(f));` by `boost::transform(arg, val.begin(), std::ref(Ftor(1.0)));` I get an error:  use of deleted function ‘void std::ref(const _Tp&&) [with _Tp = Ftor]’. What gives?

Comment: You can't safely pass a reference to a temporary. It's a safety precaution built into boosts reference wrapper class

Comment: So if I have lots of `transform`s in a loop where the overhead might count... do I prefer, A: 
`for(/* ... */ ) { tmp=Ftor(x); boost::transform(arg,val.begin(),std::ref(tmp));}` or B: `for(/* ... */ ) { boost::transform(arg,val.begin(),Ftor(x));}`

Comment: I'll answer that myself: A wins by a long shot. Solution: in a loop with N iterations I get the following operations (counting each constructor and destructor as 1)
    A: N (init) + 1 (...) = N+1 ops.
    B: N (init) + N(copy) + 2N (...) = 4N.ops. That's amazing, I never thought the may be such a big difference!

Comment: Well, as you've seen for my example that would indicate the compiler is not very good. Or you forgot to make it fair again. Can you show the exact code? Note that the two might not actually do the same thing at all (depending on what `Ftor::operator()` does). A good compiler would typically even optimize the repeated construction away (recognizing it could just reuse the same stack space each iteration. In fact, it could still vectorize the loop etc.).

Comment: Without the exact benchmark code, there's nothing we can say. With the benchmark code, I'll revisit later tonight. For now you're counting arbitrary operations, which might not even take (significant) time in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100914/discussion-between-sehe-and-rytis).